# USB Mouse stopped working in Win 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, mouse

The mouse has stopped working.

Spec:
Windows 7 x64
Logitech M9 mouse (wired)
core 2 Duo

It is definitely not a hardware issue, as I have a dual boot system and everything works tip top on the other partition, which is a similar install on Win7x64.

This issue may have been caused by a virus, as it happened shortly after my virus scanner detected it and cleaned it.

In hardware manager, it refuses to detect that the mouse is actually a mouse.

I have removed, deleted, unistalled, updated & reinstalled all of the mouse drivers and also the USB drivers & Intel drivers.  Still there remains some items not recognised in the machine config.

the mouse refuses to work, despite all of my best efforts.

[image: Device Manager]

[image: Mouse Properties, Hardware]

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Does a *different* USB mouse work? Does it work on a different USB port? Do other USB peripherals work?

Comment: I have tried other mouse and other ports and it still doesn't work, however, other USB devices work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Rebuilding  the INFCACHE.1 file in C:\windows\system32\driverstore folder.  Rename the INFCACHE.1 file to INFCACHE.1bak and then restarted the machine.  After it was booted up I connected the USB device and after a few minutes the INFCACHE.1 file is rebuilt automatically.  The ability to rename the file though requires to change the Owner and Permissions via the security tab by right clicking the INFCACHE.1 file and then going to Properties.

Hope this helps

Comment: In my case there is no INFCACHE.1 nor something similar.